# agar.io connecting thru wifi. How to make it happen?

Tags: java

I have ogar on my main pc(windows) and I can't connect at that server on laptop. They are both on same wifi, but diiftent os(Xp and 10). I cannot install hamachi or any program like that.

I tried to do this:

agar.io/?ip=127.0.0.1:913(913 its valid port and i connected like this on my pc)

and then I changed it to 192.168.0.1 and it still didn't work.

Comment: This problem doesn't fit under the Java tag, nor does it appear to be about programming at all. You might want to consider posting on another forum.

Comment: What forum? How could i connect to server?

Comment: Try disabling firewall and making sure you port forwarded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should post this question on a gaming forum. This forum is for programming related questions only.

By the way, if you want to connect your laptop and your "main pc" to the same server, follow this steps:

1. From your "main pc" go to `agar.io`
2. Change the gamemode from `FFA` to `party`
3. Now click on `Create`
4. A link will be displayed, go to that link from your laptop

Now your "main pc" and your laptop will be connected to the same match (the same server).

Comment: But i not offical server, self hosting with "ogar"